# Procedural Space Texture has Unwanted Red Streak when Viewing from Head-On Angles

Tags: texturing, materials, shader-nodes, procedural, reflection

So I built this material all-by-myself with information learned in a few other procedural texture material tutorials. It's meant to be a stylized space texture, with moving purple and red space clouds. The material looks the way I want it to! Until I rotate the viewport around and see this terrible red refraction-esque streak running through the texture. It's really strange, I can't really figure out what's causing it or how to remove it.

I tried a few things and I'm sure it's not the lighting causing it because it appears when the lights are off as well. The streak appears in both material preview and rendered mode. The streak appears flat no matter what the underlying geometry is shaped like, again in both material preview and rendered mode. This streak appears in the proper render as well.

Turning the "Normalize" checkbox off in the Noise Texture node removes the streak but instead makes the clouds in the texture only appear along that streak, and I don't want that either.

Here is a Google Drive with the node setup, example images, and a video of how the streak behaves in the rendered view in the viewport:
[Google Drive Folder with Video and FBX export](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1aCxwmOb7ersftnkSQmrhCRIXi6alKbP6?usp=drive_link)

Any help getting rid of this strange streak would be greatly appreciated! I cannot seem to find anyone else who has seen this issue.
[image: The red streak appearing in rendered view when all lights are off. It appears the same with the lights on.]
[image: An angle from which the red streak is not seen in rendered view.]
[image: The node setup making the Stylized Space material.]
[image: Image with "Normalize" turned off in the Noise Texture Node is still very undesirable.]

I can't seem to resolve the streak issue.

Comment: Is there a reason why you have drivers on the Y coordinate of two of the `Mapping` nodes right after the `Texture Coordinate` Node? That is suspicious

Comment: Please edit your question to include the screenshots/images as embedded images. This makes it easier for others to understand the issue without relying on an external site which may not exist in future.

Comment: @a-python-script The Y coordinate drivers in the mapping nodes are moving the space clouds around, and far as I can tell they're working correctly. Removing the drivers stops the movement but otherwise has no effect on the red streak. Thank you.

Comment: @RichSedman Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: Most of this stuff is fine.  The thing you're doing that *doesn't* make sense is using a bunch of things that aren't normals as normals.  In combination with fresnel, that means that you're mixing stuff in at a particular view angle that's pretty much arbitrary-- mostly, this is going be world space 1,1,1 vector, up, to the right, and away.

Comment: @NathanThank you, this helped me out!

Answer (score 1):

Well lots of fiddling and I seem to have resolved the problem. Then that changed the look so I fiddled with that, too, then I added some random space things floating about above the stars and below the clouds.

[image: Node Setup with Streak Resolved]

[image: The Icosphere with the material looking very nice]